# JQuery Mobile: Changing button text when the button is clicked

Tags: jquery, button, text, mobile

I have a question for any seasoned programmer who might be able to help me and my team member get our project working.

The problem is, we are making a game using JQuery mobile, and for the game to work we need to change the text of a button by simply clicking it, and change back again when clicked once more.

For example: If the button had a "O" on it and it was pressed it would change to an "X" and back again to a "O" if it was pressed once again.

We have been trying many different approaches with no success, and as we are pretty much on our own with this we would appreciate the advice of someone who has a better understanding of JQM.

Here is a link to JSFiddle with what we have manged to make.

http://jsfiddle.net/jonsky/qh9br/1/

Answer (score 0):

This should work http://jsfiddle.net/shamanu4/SCEZa/

The main trick is that button caption is not bormed by button itself but by span tag

```
  <div class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-c" data-theme="c" aria-disabled="false">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
      <span class="ui-btn-text">o</span>     <!-- too see the result you have to change this --> 
    </span>
    <input id="1" class="ingame ui-btn-hidden ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-c" type="button" data-inline="true" data-role="button" value="o" aria-disabled="false" data-theme="c">
      <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
        <span class="ui-btn-text"></span>
      </span>
    </input>
  </div>
```